# PHP preg_replace reuse editted match in replacement

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create an URL matching pattern where the route parameters can be read.

This is what I have:

```
$routePattern = '/test/{id}/edit';
// Can I strip the opening and closing bracket from `$0` here?
$regexPattern = '#^' . preg_replace('#{[\w]+}#', '(?P<$0>[\w]+)', $routePattern) . '$#';
// Matching done here...
```

The problem is that this will result in: `#^test/(?P<{id}>[\w]+)/edit$#`.
But I would like that the brackets get stripped from `id`. So I would like the following result: `#^test/(?P<id>[\w]+)/edit$#`.

How is this possible in a clean way? This is the non clean way I found:

```
$routePattern = '/test/{id}/edit';
$regexPattern = '#^' . preg_replace('#{[\w]+}#', '(?P<$0>[\w]+)', $routePattern) . '$#';
$regexPattern = str_replace(['{', '}'], '', $regexPattern);
// Matching done here...
```

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` might be what you need https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [capturing subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) by surrounding the `\w+` in parenthesis:

```
preg_replace('#{([\w]+)}#', '(?P<$1>[\w]+)', $routePattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a capture group, and backreference that:

```
({)(.)*(})
```

Should catch it. Then backreference it with `$2` instead of `$0`

So..

```
$regexPattern = '#^' . preg_replace('#({)([\w]+)(})#', '(?P<$2>[\w]+)', $routePattern) . '$#';
// Matching done here...
```

Like that?

This is a great resource for regex'ing things:
https://regexr.com/